# How do I extract data from text within Expect

Tags: bash, sed, tcl, expect

I would like to get exact number extracted during using Expect script. Look at this snippet of code:

```
spawn /opt/nsr/nsr_adv_config.sh create
expect "*Your selection:*"
puts "[ exec echo '$expect_out(buffer)' | grep "Generic (Other)" | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*//' | sed 's/ .*//' ]"
```

My output from *nsr adv config.sh create* is right now:

```
Please select one (number) from the list below.
    1  C-NTDB DSA node - Apertio database
    2  C-NTDB DBM node - Hypersonic database
    3  C-NTDB PGW node - CommandLog files
    4  IS-Linux (ISL)  - Linux Installation Server for C-NTDB nodes
    5  Generic (Other)

-> Your selection:
```

What I want is to get extracted number following *Generic (Other)* and later use it to send as *Your selection*, so my preferred output would be just *5*. On bash my grep and sed works correctly, but I cannout find how to make it work with Expect's exec command.

An error I'm receiving right now is:

```
invalid command name ":blank:"
    while executing
":blank:"
    invoked from within
"[:blank:]"
    invoked from within
"exec echo '$expect_out(buffer)' | grep "Generic (Other)" | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*//' | sed 's/ .*//' "
    invoked from within
"puts "[ exec echo '$expect_out(buffer)' | grep "Generic (Other)" | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*//' | sed 's/ .*//' ]""
    (file "./dev.exp" line 16)
```

I have already tried to treat ex. [ and ] as special characters and use them with \ , but it did not helped.

Comment: Try to use 'system' instead of exec: puts "[ system echo '$expect_out(buffer)' | grep "Generic (Other)" | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*//' | sed 's/ .*//' ]"

Comment: Sorry, did not helped. Still the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line will not work:

```
puts "[ exec echo '$expect_out(buffer)' | grep "Generic (Other)" | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*//' | sed 's/ .*//' ]"
```

The key issue here is that `'` is not a special character to Tcl *at all*. Instead, you need to use `{`…`}` to do the same idea (I also remove the outer `"` characters; they don't help or hinder other than to make things longer to write out):

```
puts [exec echo {$expect_out(buffer)} | grep "Generic (Other)" | sed {s/[[:blank:]]*//} | sed {s/ .*//}]
```

Yet I don't think that's quite what you want. I think you'll actually be better off with this:

```
puts [exec grep "Generic (Other)" << $expect_out(buffer) | sed {s/[[:blank:]]*//;s/ .*//}]
```

Indeed, you'll be even better off with this more-complex sed script that does the bulk of the work:

```
puts [exec sed -n {
    /Generic \(Other\)/ {
        s/[[:blank:]]*//
        s/ .*//
        p
    }
} << $expect_out(buffer)]
```

Or you can put the code in pure Tcl (with what is pretty obviously a fairly direct translation):

```
foreach line [split $expect_out(buffer) "\n"] {
    if {[string match "*Generic (Other)*" $line]} {
        regsub {[[:blank:]]*} $line "" line
        regsub { .*} $line "" line
        puts $line
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, the third code snippet works exactly as I want, thanks!